# Webpack warning on windows - There is another module with an equal name when case is ignored

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, webpack

When I run demo on windows10 X64 from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html, I get a large number of warning. e.g.:

```
WARNING in ./~/.npminstall/rxjs/5.0.0-beta.6/rxjs/Notification.js
There is another module with an equal name when case is ignored.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Rename module if multiple modules are expected or use equal casing if one module is expected.

WARNING in E:/zc_test/angular2-webpack/~/.npminstall/rxjs/5.0.0-beta.6/rxjs/Notification.js
There is another module with an equal name when case is ignored.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Rename module if multiple modules are expected or use equal casing if one module is expected.

WARNING in E:/zc_test/angular2-webpack/~/.npminstall/process/0.11.5/process/browser.js
There is another module with an equal name when case is ignored.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Rename module if multiple modules are expected or use equal casing if one module is expected.

WARNING in ./~/.npminstall/process/0.11.5/process/browser.js
There is another module with an equal name when case is ignored.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Rename module if multiple modules are expected or use equal casing if one module is expected.
```

and when I use `e:\...` in cmd, get `WARNING in E:/...`, use `E:\...` in cmd, get `WARNING in e:/...`, all warnings are for the same node modules.

node: 6.3.1

webpack: 1.13.0